# Discrete groups G whose full C*-algebra C*(G) is not MF?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

This is a cheap rip-off of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66103/discrete-groups-g-whose-full-c-algebra-cg-is-not-quasidiagonal), but I am genuinely interested in an answer.

Is there a known example of a countable discrete group G whose full group C*-algebra C*(G) is not MF?

Let us recall that a separable C*-algebra $A$ is MF if it embeds into
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty M_{k_n} / \bigoplus_n M_{k_n}, $$
for some sequence $(k_n)$ of natural numbers.

The answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66103/discrete-groups-g-whose-full-c-algebra-cg-is-not-quasidiagonal) show that there are full group C*-algebras that aren't quasidiagonal - which is a stronger condition than being MF. (They are equivalent in the case of nuclear C*-algebras, but $C^*_r(G)$ is nuclear if and only if $G$ is amenable, in which case $C^*_r(G)$ is quasidiagonal.) I can't see whether the group C*-algebras in the answers there shouldn't be MF (and I am fairly confident that the arguments there don't show they are non-MF).

Comment: Nice question. BTW, I believe "in which case" is a rather recent and rather difficult result :)

Comment: Shameless plugging: if every countable discrete group has full Cstar algebra which is MF, this would give a positive answer to this old question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78948/ (see Ken Dykema's answer there)

Comment: It's not even clear if $\mathrm{C}^*(G)$ is always finite.