# Group which is not MF or AF

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras

Does someone know example of group (countable, discrete) which can not be embedded (monomorphism) into
$$ U(\prod M_n/\oplus M_n)$$
unitary group of universal MF-algebra? Or example of group which can not be embedded into $U(A)$ - unitary group of some AF-algebra $A$? It seems, that notions of MF-group and AF-group (groups which admit embeddings, we are mentioned above) are similar to notion of hyperlinearity of group.
Does someone know interesting facts about MF-groups and AF-groups?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before on MO?

Comment: This is an open problem.

Comment: Related to this question, but not exactly the same http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221703/discrete-groups-g-whose-full-c-algebra-cg-is-not-mf